# What is the meaning of the word "along" in this context?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am a bit confused with the usage of the word "along" in a sentence from some lecture slides

"check if X lies on the path along existing neighbors"

Does this mean that X is structured in this form: foo ----- X ----- bar

or: foo ----- bar ---- X

Thanks

Comment: More context needed.

Comment: it is a sentence from slide not much context. I would have understood otherwise

Comment: There are no other slides in this same series, and no topic known for the lecture?

Comment: That's not a standard usage of the word "along", as far as I can tell. You'd have to figure out the meaning from context.

Comment: @BrianDonovan yeah that's what I thought first. Looking at the other slides I will assume that the teacher meant is scenario 1: foo ---- X ---- bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Along" has been misplaced in the sentence.  The sentence, to be grammatically correct, should read: "Check to determine if X lies along the same line as defined by existing values."  "Neighbors" is a bad choice of words for this idea entirely.  While it does carry a suggestion that two things are part of a straight-line contiguous row of objects, such as houses on a street, streets need not be straight.  Also, one can have neighbors in a neighborhood who do not have their houses either next to one's own and/or on some arbitrarily-defined reference line, such as a street.  For this reason, I would not have used the word "neighbors" anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: The context probably is graph theory, in which *straight-line* is not a meaningful concept.  In [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), “a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which connect a sequence of vertices”.   Neighbors is a basic term in graph theory.  The neighbors of a vertex are those vertices connected to it or from it by an edge.  Probably *along* should be replaced by a word like *between*

Comment: @jwpat7 you're correct, the context is graph theory